# Does Stripe payments support Samsung Pay in UAE?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, stripe-payments, samsung-pay

The problem i am facing is, i want to use the Stripe for the project based on Flutter, which will be an app working on Android and iOS devices.

I know, Stripe can provide me the opportunity to integrate Apple Pay and Google Pay.
But what if i need to integrate the Samsung Pay as well?
Is it supported by Stripe as well?

Comment: Samsung Pay is not currently supported

Answer (score 1):

Samsung Pay is currently not supported on Stripe.

Comment: I wonder why this is. I doubt Samsung would be unwilling, and considering there are more Samsungs sold globally than there are iPhones, it would make perfect business sense for Stripe to integrate Samsung Pay into the new Payment Element.